# Error after installing CakePhp in Production setup

Tags: cakephp-2.0

> guys could somebody please help me out? I have just installed cakephp in my localhost
>   then I'm already getting errors.
>   Please check this out for reference [screenshot of entire page](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/720/6838049286.png)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a table exist namely 'reservations' in your database for which code is not exist.
Sp please create ReservationController.php in Controller folder as well as its Model in 'Model' Folder.

If you want to access any methods of the RestrictionController you have to create view files accordingly.